# Handle all Ajax exceptions in one place and return error to view

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a fairly large application with dozens of Ajax calls.  I want to log any of the errors that come up in the ajax calls in one single place.  I put a jquery alert on my _Layout.cshmtl view so that the exception can get passed into the alert.  How do I return a error string from my HandleExceptionAttribute class to my view?

Controller Action:

```
[HandleExceptionAttribute]
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize ( Roles = "View Only,Admin,A-Team Manager,A-Team Analyst" )]
    public JsonResult GetEntitySorMapTable ( Decimal entityId )
    {
        //Added this line to hit my HandleExceptionAttribute
        throw new DivideByZeroException();

        List<EntitySorMapView> entitySorMaps = null;

        if (entityId == 0)
        {
            entitySorMaps = new List<EntitySorMapView> ( );
        }

        entitySorMaps = RealmsModel.RealmsDataInterface ( ).SelectEntitySorMapByEntityId ( entityId );

        String data = HtmlHelpers.BuildEntitySorMapTable ( entitySorMaps );

        return new JsonResult ( )
        {
            Data = data,
            MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
        };            
    }
```

Error Attribute:

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest() && filterContext.Exception != null)
        {
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                Data = new
                {
                    filterContext.Exception.Message,
                    filterContext.Exception.StackTrace
                }
            };
            filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnException(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

_Layout View ajax error script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ajaxError(function (xhr, status, error) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        if (xhr.error != null)
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText + ' status: ' + status + ' Exception: ' + error);
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
{
    Data = new { errorMessage = "Your custom error message" },
    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
};
```

and in your _layout.cshtml file

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqxhr, settings, thrownError) {
    if (jqxhr.error != null) {
        var result = JSON.parse(jqxhr.responseText);
            console.log(result.errorMessage)
    }
});
```